# Rails: Create an inverse relationship between friends

Tags: ruby-on-rails, web-deployment

I'm trying to build a facebook clone and finally got friends acceptance to work, but now I'm trying to have a bidirectional relationship between the two friends.

```
friendship.rb

class Friendship < ApplicationRecord
  #after_create :create_inverse_relationship
  after_destroy :destroy_inverse_relationship

  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :friend, class_name: "User"



  def create_inverse_relationship
    #byebug
    friend.friendships.build(friend_id: current_user.id)

  end

  def destroy_inverse_relationship
    friendship = friend.friendship.find_by(friend: user)
    friendship.destroy if friendship
  end
end
```

---

When a user accepts a friend request I get an error in my create_inverse_relationships method saying:

```
 undefined method `friendships' for nil:NilClass
```

---

```
    friend_request.rb

    class FriendRequest < ApplicationRecord
      belongs_to :user
      belongs_to :friend, class_name: 'User'

    def accept
      user.friends << friend
      Friendship.new.create_inverse_relationship
    end

   def destroy
   end

  end
```

---

```
user.rb

class User < ApplicationRecord

has_many :friend_requests, dependent: :destroy
has_many :pending_friends, through: :friend_requests, source: :friend
has_many :friendships, dependent: :destroy
has_many :friends, through: :friendships
# Include default devise modules. Others available are:
# :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable
devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
     :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable
end
```

---

```
   friend_request_controller.rb

   class FriendRequestsController < ApplicationController
before_action :set_friend_request, except: [:index, :create]

def index
    @incoming = FriendRequest.where(friend: current_user)
    @outgoing = current_user.friend_requests
end

def create
    @user = User.find(current_user)
    friend = User.find(params[:friend_id])
    @friend_request = current_user.friend_requests.new(friend_id: friend.id)

    if @friend_request.save
        redirect_to user_path(current_user)
    end
end

def update
    friend = User.find(params[:friend_id])
    @friend_request = current_user.friend_requests.find_by(friend_id: friend.id)
    @friend_request.accept


end

def destroy
    @friend_request.destroy
end


private

def set_friend_request
    @friend_request = FriendRequest.find(params[:id])
end
end
```

---

Any guidance would be greatly appreciated

Comment: `Friendship.new.create_inverse_relationship` you've not set a friend here which leads to the error.  You won't be able to use `current_user` in your model either.

Comment: i wont be able to use current_user in the friend request model or the friendship model?

Comment: No, current user will be defined in a controller I'd imagine, you'd have to pass it in as an argument to use it